# Python Regex Parser

Tags: python, regex, parsing, alert, snort

I need to fine tune the following regex. Right now it gives me srcip, dstip, srcport, dstport and date. I need it to also give me the protocol (UDP, TCP). Here is the line it needs to parse:

```
03/09-13:00:59.136048  [**] [1:2003410:9] ET POLICY FTP Login Successful [**] [Classification: Misc activity] [Priority: 3] {TCP} 172.16.112.100:21 -> 206.48.44.18:1039
```

Here is my current regex:

```
([0-9/]+)-([0-9:.]+)\s+.*?(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}):(\d{1,5})\s+->\s+(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}):(\d{1,5})
```

Additionally, it needs to be able to handle requests that have no ports associated with them (like ICMP):

```
03/09-13:57:26.523602  [**] [1:2100368:7] GPL ICMP_INFO PING BSDtype [**] [Classification: Misc activity] [Priority: 3] {ICMP} 172.16.114.50 -> 172.16.112.207
```

Answer (score 1):

This regex should work with what you want:

```
([0-9\/]+)-([0-9:.]+)\s+.*?\s\{(\w+)\}\s(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}):?(\d{1,5})?\s+->\s+(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}):?(\d{1,5})?
```

I have added `\s\{(\w+)\}\s` to match the protocol. I also made the protocol and the colon preceding it optional.